# Python Encryption program

Tags: python, encryption

I am trying to write a substitution encryption program where it shifts the alphabet according to a random number. This is done letter by letter or character by character

This is the error in which I get.

```
File "./encrypt.py", line 35, in <module>
    print("after encryption: ", encrypt(text))
File "./encrypt.py", line 26, in encrypt
    cipher = cipher + chr((ord(char) + str(function1()) - 65) % 27 + 65) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Is there any solutions out there????

```
import random

text = input("enter string: ")

number = 0
number += len(text)

def encrypt(string):

  def otp(filename):
    file = open(filename + ".txt", "a")
    file.write(str(function1()) + "\n")
    file.close()

  def function1():
    for num in range(number):
      shift = str(random.randint(1,26))
      print(shift)

  cipher = ''
  for char in string:
    if char == ' ':
        cipher = cipher + chr((ord(char) + str(function1()) - 65) % 27 + 65)
        otp("onetimepad")
    elif  char.isupper():
        cipher = cipher + chr((ord(char) + str(function1()) - 65) % 27 + 65)
        otp("onetimepad")
    else:
        cipher = cipher + chr((ord(char) + str(function1()) - 97) % 27 + 97)
        otp("onetimepad")

  return cipher

print("original string: ", text)
print("after encryption: ", encrypt(text))
```

Comment: "function1" doesn't `return` anything explicitly. So it returns "None" by default. To convert this to `str`ing isn't of much use here.

Comment: What do you understand from that error message? Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any such destructive edits will be reverted. Please see [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221) for more information on how deleting content works on this site.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is quite clear.  The cited line of code has only two `+` operations, and the first one clearly violates the available definitions of `+`

```
ord(char) + str(function1())
```

You have an integer on the left; on the right, you explicitly converted the return value to string.  Decide what you're trying to do and fix your expression.  It *seems* that you're trying to do an integer calculation of a new ordinal value.  The solution may be simply to *not* convert the function's return value.

Comment: No, I can't.  You neglected to specify what this is doing.  You posted your *entire* program, rather than the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Your function returns `None`, and there are other errors in your program.  I would have to rewrite multiple problems, which is out of scope for Stack Overflow.  I made a suggestion; what doesn't work with that?